# $dU=dQ$ and $dU=TdS$, but $dQ$ not always equal to $TdS$? Why?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

$$ dU = dQ+dW $$ $$ dU=TdS-pdV $$ The equations above are always true for a thermodynamic state of a certain system. Now let's say that we have a situation where $dW=0$, this tells us that $$ dU=dQ $$ $$ dU=TdS $$But still I can't write $ dQ=TdS $, since this only works for a reversible change of my system. So if I don't have a reversible system I can work with $ dU=dQ $ and $ dU=TdS $, but I can't work with $ dQ=TdS $.

I get this, but I have been trying to figure out *why* this is, and I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: did you understand what you were getting confused about?

Comment: yes, thank you! I understood after reading your answer and a bit from this link: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Comment: Reminding yourself that the entropy is a state function within the context of thermodynamics will tell you all you need to solve this mystery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In $dS = \frac{dQ}{T}$, the $dQ$ is the heat exchange on a **reversible** path from the initial state to the final state, irrespective of how the process is actually carried out.

Answer (score 8):

Even if dW = 0 (e.g., constant volume), you can't write dQ=TdS for an irreversible process because, for irreversible heating or cooling of a body, T is not constant spatially within the body (i.e., T varies with spatial position).  For transient irreversible heating, the temperatures near the boundary are hotter than in the interior, and for transient irreversible cooling, the reverse is true.  So what value of T are you supposed to use?  If you use the value of T at the boundary at which the heat transfer Q is occurring (i.e., $T = T_B$), you find that $dQ<T_BdS$.  More precisely, $$\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}<\Delta S$$This is just the statement of the Clausius Inequality.

Comment: But that equation dU=TdS−pdV is always valid, right? If we have an irreversible isochoric process, dV should be 0, so dU= TdS.  -----(1) also, dU = q + w always, here w is zero, so dU = q ----------(2) If you combine 1 and 2, we should get q = TdS, This is what's confusing, it clearly isn't.

Comment: This is the reason why I never use differentials to describe irreversible processes.  I reserve the use of differentials only for reversible paths.  The equation $dU=TdS-PdV$ describes the mutual variations in dU, dS, and dV between two closely neighboring thermodynamic equilibrium states.  But, if you want to move between two equilibrium states that are separated by a finite amount, you can't simply integrate $T_BdS$ to get Q.  For example, you heat a body from T1 to T2, with the boundary held const at T2.  For this change $\Delta U=Q=mC(T_2-T_1)$, but $\Delta S=mC\ln{(T_2/T_1)}>Q/T_2$

Answer (score 4):

For an arbitrary process between equilibrium states of a closed system, we have
$$
\Delta U = Q + W
$$
which is just conservation of energy.

If the process happens quasi-statically, state variables are well-defined at each point in time and we can go to an infinitesimal description
$$
dU = \delta Q + \delta W
$$
where
$$
\delta Q \leq TdS \qquad \delta W \geq -p dV
$$
Equality holds if the process is reversible, ie when the change in entropy is given by $dS = \delta Q/T$ without additional entropy production (due to friction, chemical reactions, what have you...).

In general, work performed externally on a system can get converted into heat within the system, and an infinitesimal descriptions in terms of energy flows and state variables won't match.

Explicitly, we have
$$
\delta Q = TdS - T\,\delta S_\text{irrev} \\
\delta W = -pdV + T\,\delta S_\text{irrev}
$$
where $\delta S_\text{irrev}$ is the additional entropy produced compared to a reversible process.

Comment: But $$dU=TdS-pdV=δQ+δW \rightarrow δQ=TdS$$ What I am missing?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas: I guess my answer should better read $\delta W\geq -pdV$. We have $\delta Q = T(dS - \delta S_\text{irrev})$ and $\delta W = -pdV + T\delta S_\text{irrev}$. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion, to a large extent, is caused by notation. It is unfortunate that the same letter $d$ is used for two very different purposes.

In $dU = TdS - PdV$, $d$ stands for the exterior derivative operator, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

In $dU = dQ + dW$, $d$ stands for "infinitesimal change". Some authors write instead $\delta U = \delta Q + \delta W$ to highlight the distinction. I will follow this practice.

A system of ideal gas, *in equilibrium*, has well-defined $P$, $V$, $T$, and $S$. Not all of them are independent. In fact, you can pick any two of them to fully specify the state of the system. In contrast, a system that is not in equilibrium does not have well-defined $P$ or $T$.

When we describe a state *in equilibrium* using $(P,T)$ as our coordinates, any point $(P,T)$ also fully determines $V$, $S$, and $U$. So we can write $$V = V(P,T)\\ S = S(P,T) \\ U = U(P,T).$$

In this notation, $dV$ is the gradient of function $V$, and similarly for $dS$ and $dU$. (Gradients are one-forms in the language of differential forms.) These are really geometrical objects. And the equation $dU = TdS - PdV$ expresses an equality between three gradients. We could have chosen $V$ and $P$ as our coordinates instead of $P$ and $T$. The equality would be the same.

When we are going through an irreversible process $\alpha$, the intermediate states do not always have well-defined $P$ or $T$. So something like $dU = TdS - PdV$ or even $\delta U = T \delta S - P \delta V$ really is meaningless. Instead, we have $$\delta U = \delta W + \delta Q,$$ which is simply energy conservation. We cannot plot the process $\alpha$ on the $P-T$ graph. However, if the state $A$ at the beginning of the process, and the state $B$ at the end of the process, are in equilibrium, we can plot these two points on the graph, and join them with an arbitrary curve $\beta$. Any such curve describes a reversible process, which starts and ends at the same points as the irreversible one that we are trying to study.

We then have, by Kelvin’s statement of the second law, $$\int_\alpha \frac{\delta Q}{T} < \int_\beta \frac{\delta Q}{T} = \int_\beta dS. $$

An crucial point is what $T$ means here. It is the temperature of the immediate environment of the system. (We assume the immediate environment is in equilibrium). On $\alpha$, that's as much as we can say. On $\beta$, however, it is also the same temperature of the system itself.

It is tempting to write the inequality above as $\delta Q < TdS$. But it is strictly speaking incorrect.

We are going along two *different* paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and there is no *valid* one-to-one correspondence between points on $\alpha$ and points on $\beta$ except at $A$ and $B$.

Some explanation on the term *valid* is required. Naively, we could parametrize $\alpha$ by $t$, and define a particular $\beta$, such that at each $t$, $\beta(t)$ is in equilibrium and $P(\beta(t)) = P(\alpha(t))$ and $T(\beta(t)) = T(\alpha(t))$. Note again, that on $\alpha$, $P$ and $T$ are of the immediate environment. A minor nuisance is that $\delta V$ on $\alpha$ is in general different to $\delta V$ on $\beta$. But let's ignore it for now.

A bigger problem is that we won't be able to run a loop connecting $\alpha(t)$, $\alpha(t+\delta t)$, $\beta(t+\delta t)$, $\beta(t)$, and back to $\alpha(t)$. The last segment is the reverse of $\alpha(t)$ to $\beta(t)$, which is irreversible. Without such a loop, we cannot use a similar argument that leads to $\int_\alpha \frac{\delta Q}{T} < \int_\beta \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ to establish any inequality in a differential form.

At the end of the day, if you really want to write down things like $\delta Q < T dS$, just remember that it will give you the right result only *after* you have integrated both sides. On the LHS, you get $\Delta Q$ which is specific to the irreversible process being studied. On the RHS, you get something only depends on the states of starting and ending points.

Answer (score 0):

Here $U(S,V) $ is a function of two variables, $S$ and $V$. $U$ is a state function, which means that, regardless of the path taken between states $S_1,V_1$ and $S_2,V_2$, the change of $U$ is the same: $\Delta U = U(S_2,V_2)-U(S_1,V_1)$.

On the other hand, $Q$ and $W$ are not functions of state - they depend on how the variables $S,V$ change when we go from state 1 to state 2, i.e., from the path we take. Hence, these are not true differentials (one sometimes uses different notation to indicate this fact, such as $\partial Q,\partial W$ or $\delta Q,\delta W$ or crossed differentials.) Thus, strictly speaking, writing $dQ=TdS$ doesn't make sense mathematically without specifying the path along which system moves (that is $dW=0$.)

Using [Clausius inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem), $\delta S\geq \frac{\delta Q}{T_{env}}$ involves some additional nuances: not only the differentials are not true differentials, but the temperature in this inequality is that of the environment, rather than the system temperature - the two are the same for a reversible process, but not for an irreversible one.

Answer (score 0):

In your isochoric ($\delta w = 0$) scenario, this equation is *always* valid $$dU = \delta Q =  T_{sys}dS_{sys} = T_{surr}dS_{surr}$$
*regardless* of reversibility, as it is merely the definition of entropy: $$dS_X = \frac{\delta Q}{T_X} $$
where $X$ is either only *just the system* or only *just the surroundings* -- meaning, you cannot just "mix" the two, unless...

..the process you are dealing is *reversible*! And as such, will have the *additional* quality that
$$\delta Q = T_{surr}dS_{sys} = T_{sys}dS_{surr} \Longleftrightarrow T_{sys} = T_{surr}, dS_{sys} = dS_{surr} \;(\text{if }\delta Q \ne 0)$$
(finally letting you mix up those subscripts as you wish!)